# Python / Django - problems with serving media files (which do not appear in the folder)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-media

Trying to add media files via admin.py, they do not appear in the folder they are supposed to be. Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_in_dev', 'media_root')
```

As far as I understand, this means that all the downloaded media files are supposed to be saved in the `project_folder/static_in_dev/media_root`

**models.py**

```
class GalleryCupsModel(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cups/%Y/%m/%d')
```

And this is supposed to create folder 'cups' with year/month/day in the media_root folder, isn't it?

**admin.py**

```
class GalleryCupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['photo']

admin.site.register(GalleryCupsModel, GalleryCupsAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^cups/all/$", "gallery_cups.views.cups", name="cups"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**project tree**

```
├── gallery_cups
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── __pycache__
├── LC
│   └── __pycache__
├── static_in_dev
│   ├── media
│   ├── media_root
│   ├── my_static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── static_root
│       ├── admin
│       │   ├── css
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   ├── img
│       │   │   └── gis
│       │   └── js
│       │       ├── admin
│       │       └── vendor
│       │           ├── jquery
│       │           └── xregexp
│       ├── css
│       ├── img
│       │   ├── header
│       │   └── portfolio
│       └── js
└── templates
```

The problem is the files, which I upload via admin.py, do not appear in the project_folder/static_in_dev/media_root, though I see them in the admin.py panel as a list of added images.

I've searched a lot but looks like I miss something crucial, but can not get what exactly. Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)` actually goes up one level, so you might be storing your images outside your project root. Check that out and let us know.

Comment: Do you mean, it might create a static_in_dev/media/ folders outside of the project? I will definitely check it today (though have no chance to do this in the moment).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Let us know if that worked for you so I can make a detailed answer.

Comment: In `project_folder/static_in_dev/media_root`, `project_folder` is your project or your app folder? You also should sow the `BASE_DIR` setting.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it today out and let you know, if that worked.

Comment: @AlexMorozov, thank you for the answer, it was right the needed moment. Being unintentionally during video lectures creates a looot of problems..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your project folder structure `MEDIA_ROOT` should be defined:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_dev', 'media_root')
```

because `static_in_dev` folder is in your project directory which is the `BASE_DIR`.